# HTML Input Type Number with Leading Zero on Input

Tags: javascript, html, leading-zero

I have HTML Input Type=Number with maxlength='6' and I want it to have leading zeros *while* typing certain numbers. Leading zeros automatically adjusts depending on your number input.

**Example**:
While typing '12' in the field, it should add leading zeros making it '000012' instead, or typing '123', it should be '000123', and so on.

How can I achieve this using JS/JQuery?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=number]").addEventListener('input', addLeadingZero)

function addLeadingZero(event) {
    // get maxlength attr
    const maxLength = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("maxlength"))
    // "0".repeat(maxLength) <-- create default pad with maxlength given
    // append zero and slice last of attr maxlength value
    const newValue = ("0".repeat(maxLength) + event.target.value.toString()).slice(-maxLength);
    // change the value of input
    event.target.value = newValue
}
```

```html
<!-- @event onkeyup to make sure function run on every key up -->
<!-- @event onchange to make sure function run when we click on arrow up/down -->
<input type="number" maxlength="6">
```

To support negative value :

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=number]").addEventListener('input', addLeadingZero)

function addLeadingZero(event) {
    // get maxlength attr
    const maxLength = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("maxlength"))
    // check and flag if negative
    const isNegative = parseInt(event.target.value) < 0
    // "0".repeat(maxLength) <-- create default pad with maxlength given
    // Math.abs(event.target.value) to make sure we proceed with positive value
    // append zero and slice last of attr maxlength value
    let newValue = ("0".repeat(maxLength) + Math.abs(event.target.value).toString()).slice(-maxLength);
    // add - if flag negative is true
    if (isNegative) {
      newValue = "-"+newValue
    }
    // change the value of input
    event.target.value = newValue
}
```

```html
<!-- @event onkeyup to make sure function run on every key up -->
<!-- @event onchange to make sure function run when we click on arrow up/down -->
<input type="number" maxlength="6">
```

Note :
while this answer is correct for more smoother change please check [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863728/html-input-type-number-with-leading-zero-on-input/72864152#72864152) given by @science fun for using `addEventListener`.

edit: applied `addEventListener`.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=number]").addEventListener('input', addLeadingZero)
```

Comment: You may want to listen for the `change` event too, as right clicking and pasting doesn't trigger your function.

Comment: Thanks Rio! Exactly what I need. Good point too @WOUNDEDStevenJones , thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since I cannot comment, I will add one point as an answer:
It's better to just listen for `input` events. It's smoother and will trigger on pasting/ctrl+V.

The credit of this answer goes to *Rio A.P*

```js
function addLeadingZero(event) {

    // get maxlength attr
    const maxLength = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("maxlength"))
    // check and flag if negative
    const isNegative = parseInt(event.target.value) < 0
    // "0".repeat(maxLength) <-- create default pad with maxlength given
    // Math.abs(event.target.value) to make sure we proceed with positive value
    // append zero and slice last of attr maxlength value
    let newValue = ("0".repeat(maxLength) + Math.abs(event.target.value).toString()).slice(-maxLength);
    // add - if flag negative is true
    if (isNegative) {
      newValue = "-"+newValue
    }
    // change the value of input
    event.target.value = newValue
}

document.querySelector("input[type=number]").addEventListener('input', addLeadingZero)
```

```html
<input type="number" maxlength="6">
```